# Harmonic Function - Multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-functions

One more exercise I stepped at while strolling through papers and journals for my preparation on the semester exams for multivariable calculus.

Let $D=\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ A function $f:D \to \mathbb R$ is called *harmonic* if it's continuous, has continuous partial derivatives (maximum of second grade) in the inside of $D$ and moreover : $f_{xx}(x,y) + f_{yy}(x,y) = 0 $ $\forall (x,y)$ inside $D$. Show that such a function $f$ does not have local extrema in the inside of D. Also show that $f$ gets a maximum and minimum value in the circle $C=\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 =1\}$.

For the second part, we will use the entry which states that a continuous and real function defined in a closed and bounded subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ gets a maximum and minimum value. Thus, $f$ gets a maximum and minimum value in $D$ which is the set of points of $\mathbb R^2$ that are inside of circle (we can see that by the definition. So, $f$ gets maximum and minimum value in the circle $C=\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 =1\}$.

My question is regarding the first part. How do we prove that it does NOT have local extrema ? My attempt was the following :

$f_{xx}(x,y) + f_{yy}(x,y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow (f_x)_x(x,y) + (f_y)_y(x,y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow f'(x,y) = c(y-x)$ as a solution to the First order ODE.

Now, the derivative of $f$ : $f'(x,y) = c(y-x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow y=x$ and that's true $\forall x,y\in \{x^2 + y^2 < 1\} : x=y $ which are infinite, thus the points on which the derivative is zero are NOT finite and thus we can conclude that $f$ does NOT have local extrema in the inside of $D$.

Is my attempt correct ? Personally I think something's off of it. Any tip/correction/help will be really appreciated.

Comment: no, it does not work that way. The local solution you are considering is not (locally) unique. The proof of this fact is slightly more involved than usual for an exercise and there are actually several possible approaches. Did you, e.g., learn the mean value (in)equalities for harmonic maps?

Comment: @Thomas No, we haven't done harmonic theory. This is just a definition that was part of the exercise, so nop. We have learned the mean value theorem though.

Comment: You really need the second derivative test.

Comment: @JohnMa what do you mean ?

Comment: If $f$ has a local maximum in $\{x^2 + y^2 <1\}$ what can be say about the second derivative of $f$ at that point?

Comment: First derivative test is what I heard off and we know that if a function $f$ has a local maximum at a point $p$, then $f'(p) = 0$.

Comment: @JohnMa the second derivative test alone is too weak as far as I can tell. To the OP: John refers to the fact that in a maximum the second derivative is negativ semidefinite.

Comment: @Thomas We haven't elaborated on that, so it must be something else

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos : FYI : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test

Comment: A solution (well, outline in a question) to your question (using the property I was referring to) is found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684201/proof-of-strong-maximum-principle-for-harmonic-functions. @JohnMa I'd really like to see a proof relying only on the second derivative test and would appreciate if you could tell me (and the OP) how this works. (By _only_ I mean not referring to the Hopf lemma or anything the like).

Comment: @Thomas Probalbly the hopf lemma is the easiest one to go. (And for the second derivative one, I was referring to the weak maximum principle, so it is not really what the OP wants).